# Smart annotation

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have created many annotation in my life and now came to strange case that i need this annotation to do and dont think it is supported by Java at all. Please someone tell me that i am right or wrong.

Here is my annotation :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface DetailsField {
    public String name();
}
```

And now the question! I would like that the **default** value of the **name**() function would be the name of the field it self where I have posted the annotation.

Dont know exactly how the classloader processes the annotations, i am pretty sure that this is not implemented in a standard classloader , but could be maybe achieved by bytecode instrumentation in the time of classloading by a custom classloader ? 
(I am pretty sure if this is the only solution i would find a way around , just curious )

Any ideas? Or do i wish too much ?

Comment: You're not going to be able to default the name to the name of the field. However, if you're writing the annotation processor as well, you'll have that information to hand when you read the annotation anyway. Can't you just check if the value is null and if so, use the field name that you got by reflection instead?

Comment: Yea , thats exactly what i do now. 
And i dont think that this is a big problem. Just wanted to make sure that i don't miss a thing here , or there is something that i dont know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it is possible to instrument the bytecode (at class loading) to get this working, but this seems like a highly complicated, and possibly non-portable, solution.

The best solution to your problem is to create a class that decorates (a-la the Decorator design pattern) an instance of your annotation with the name calculation logic.

[Edit: Added the name() definition at the interface]

```
package p1;

import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class A {
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Target(ElementType.FIELD)
  public @interface DetailsField  {
     public int n1();   
     public String name() default "";     
  }

  public static class Nameable implements DetailsField {
     private final DetailsField df;
     private final Field f;

     public Nameable(Field f) {
        this.f = f;
        this.df = f.getAnnotation(DetailsField.class);
     }

     @Override
     public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
        return df.annotationType();
     }

     @Override
     public String toString() {
        return df.toString();
     }

     @Override
     public int n1() {
        return df.n1();
     }

     public String name() {
        return f.getName();
     }   
  }

  public class B {
     @DetailsField(n1=3)
     public int someField;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Field f = B.class.getField("someField");

     Nameable n = new Nameable(f);
     System.out.println(n.name()); // output: "someField"
     System.out.println(n.n1());   // output: "3"
  }
}
```